# Prerender.io gives me 504 gateway timeout

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, prerender

When using **prerender.io** to cache my AngularJS site (using Asp.Net MVC middleware) I'm getting the following error on all pages except the main page :

> The page cannot be displayed due to a gateway timeout.

I'm setting `window.prerenderReady = true` on a timer of 5 seconds.

I'm not sure if this is some IIS setting or something else.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: Send me an email at todd@prerender.io. Sounds like your middleware might not be set up correctly. Happy to help!

Comment: Hi I emailed you, waiting for response

Comment: I solved the issue, the issue was the asp.net mvc middleware on nuget. Downloaded it from github instead and recompiled it.

Comment: Our load balancer was configured to forward traffic to the servers over port :81. I had to strip out ":81" from the request URL in the source code (from github) before making the request. That solved the issue for me. I'd suggest debug outputting the request URL being sent to prerender.io. Chances are, it'll expose your issue.